# Mass budget of coastal erosion and ocean deposion

Tags: sea-level, sedimentology, erosion

[This question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/19363) made me wonder: **how much mass (or volume) of material is eroded by the sea each year? Of this mass, how much is deposited in the oceans?** (As Michael pointed out in his answer, part of the eroded material can be redeposited on another part of the shoreline.)

The bottom line is: I wonder if the increase in sea level (and subsequent increase in coastal erosion) could lead to a positive feedback because of Archimedes principle. I'd like to calculate if the volume of material deposited in the oceans is enough to make the sea level rise, or if this effect is negligible.

Comment: this is related https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/14200/how-much-does-sea-level-rise-due-to-sediment-deposition?rq=1 with numbers and all.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I thought about river input, but I figured it was more or less in balance with the sediments removed by subduction. I didn't thought about the subsidence aspect though...

Comment: Can't answer the question, would instinctively think that the effect is small compared to ice shield melting and thermal expansion and runoff from the continents into the abyss ... but idk. And slow, as you say, Wilson cycle slow maybe ...